# angular js data table ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

I am using Angular js data table. currently I need to pass row ID. Therefore I am trying to call ng-click function. but its not working. Please check the below code

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withOption('ajax', {
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: appConfig.apiUrl + "/approvalList?reqTraceId=" + $scope.requestApprovalId,
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            type: 'POST',
            data: function (d) {
                return JSON.stringify(d);

            },
            error: function (response) {
                ajaxErrorHandler.handle(response);
            }
        })

        .withDataProp('data')
        .withOption('processing', true)
        .withOption('serverSide', true)
        .withOption('scrollY', '400px')
        .withOption('scrollX', '100%')
        .withOption('scrollCollapse', true)

        .withOption('drawCallback', function (settings) {

        });

    $scope.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('traceId').withTitle('Trace ID').withClass('cus-id'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('approval.0.usr').withTitle('Name').withClass('cus-id'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('approval.0.threshold').withTitle('Match Strength %').withClass('cus-id'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('traceId').withTitle('Action').renderWith(function (data, type, full) {
            return '<div class="btn-group-xs">' +
                '  <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-xs btn-success" ng-click="passId();">' +
                '    <i class="ion ion-eye"></i>' +
                '  </button>' +
                '</div>';
        }).withClass('text-center').notSortable()
    ];
```

I am using below function for testing purpose. But Function did not call.

```
 $scope.passId= function () {
        alert("hi")
    };
```

how i call function using this code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

the function passId should be inside same controller then only it will works please check that.